# Under which circumstances is the default security profile of XRDP considered okay?

Tags: linux, rdp, raspberry-pi

In `xrdp.ini`, the base install of [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/) on my raspberry pi*, there I have the following below. I changed `crypt_level` to `high`.

```
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=high
channel_code=1
```

Now, on my own network (with no port forwarded configured on the router) when I access everything over `192.168.1.xx` I image it's default settings are sufficient.

However, if one were to install this to a public facing workstation, would (a) this default setting be too low and (b) is there a different, more hardened configuration to consider? If I gave the pi a public facing IP should I consider a different method (VNC over SSH)? Could I pipe RDP over SSH?

The pi is running the following if that makes any difference.

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7-v7+ #817 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:32:00 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```